# What does the curly brackets after language description do in markdown?

Tags: markdown

What does this markdown syntax mean?:

````
```js{3-6}
function Avatar(props) {
  return (
    // ...
  );
}
```
````

The `js` is the language to use for highlighting of course, but what are the numbers in the curly brackets?

The example is from the [React documentation](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/docs/docs/components-and-props.md). There are several other examples with different numbers.

Markdown uses [this list](https://github.com/github/linguist/blob/master/lib/linguist/languages.yml) for language recognition, but it doesn't say anything about the numbers in curly brackets.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's not a standard Markdown feature. In fact, neither are fenced code blocks.

In this case they appear to be used for highlighting lines from the snippet, e.g. see [the compiled version](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/components-and-props.html#extracting-components) where lines 3–6 are highlighted, matching the numbers shown in your snippet above:

[image]

The line highlighting functionality is provided in [this Redcarpet plugin](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/docs/_plugins/highlight_lines.rb), whose introductory comment block says in part:

> Replace Jekyll's handling of the Redcarpet code_block (which already adds
>   support for highlighting, but needs support for the very non-standard
>   "code fences with line highlights" extension).